# How to add previous job experience on my curriculum vitae while in charge of multiple departments?

Tags: resume, startup

**TLDR:** Worked at a start up where I was in charge of everything that was not finance related. Without a degree or real work experience I was responsible for all other departments and I learned myself how to do my departments (to the best I can). Now I am looking how I can best add this experience to my curriculum vitae.

I used to work for a start up company where I was in charge of everything besides finance without a degree or real work experience. During this time I pretty much learned myself how the departments should work, what needs to be done, can we or I do this on my own or should we outsource etc. I want to add this working experience in my curriculum vitae, but because I did so many different things I do not what the best way is to add this.

Some departments that I was normally working on on a regular working day:

- IT (maintenance, website, etc)
- Marketing (social media and promotions like videos)
- Logistics (shipping, customs, getting offers etc)
- Production
- Special orders, offers and complaints

How would I best add this to my curriculum vitae without making a real long story about it?

Comment: It started with 2 and when I left they had 7 employees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

*2017: Supershirts.com, Product Manager*

*Entirely maintained IT, social and marketing; led logistics, production and customer service. Grew company from two to seven staff.*

It sounds fantastic - who wouldn't want that?!